# Full Join And Distribute Evenly Based on Count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I want to join:

Table A

```
  Date     Gran1     Gran2     Gran3 
1/1/18         A         B        CD
1/1/18         A         B        EF
1/2/18         A         B        GF
1/2/18         A         B        EF
1/2/18         A         B        FR
1/2/18         A         L        EF
```

Table B

```
  Date     Gran1     Gran2     Value1    Value2
1/1/18         A         B        100       150
1/2/18         A         B        200        80
1/2/18         A         L        500        30
```

Table B does not have the same granularity as Table A. I want to join Table B to Table A and distribute the Values I am joining by the count of occurences Date, Gran1, and Gran2 occur.

My final result should look like this:

```
  Date     Gran1     Gran2     Gran3    Value1     Value2
1/1/18         A         B        CD        50         75
1/1/18         A         B        EF        50         75
1/2/18         A         B        GF     66.67      26.67  
1/2/18         A         B        EF     66.67      26.67
1/2/18         A         B        FR     66.67      26.67
1/2/18         A         L        EF       500         30
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query

```
Select a1.date1, 
        a1.gran1, 
        a1.gran2,
        a1.gran3,
        (b.value1/a2.xCount) as value1, 
        (b.value2/a2.xCount) as value2
from @tableA A1
Inner join @tableB B on A1.date1 = B.date1 
                    and a1.gran1 = b.gran1 
                    and a1.gran2 = b.gran1
inner join (select date1, gran1, gran2, count(*) xCount 
                from  @tableA 
                group by date1, gran1, gran2) A2 on A1.date1 = A2.date1 
                                                and a1.gran1 = a2.gran1 
                                                and a1.gran2 = a2.gran2
```

Comment: Looks very much the same as my answer. Good to see we are thinking the same.

Comment: This looks ok thanks, I am still having trouble for some reason that I am investigating. For some reason, with my actual dataset, the final value joined is less than the original. I'm wondering if it has to do with NULL's. There is no missing data in the original dataset joining onto tableA. I'll accept this but if you have any insights into why this may be happening it would be really helpful.

Comment: also should it be for the first inner join - `a1.gran2 = b.gran2 instead of a1.gran2 = b.gran1`?

Comment: Will this still work if tableA has rows that are not found in tableB?

Answer (score 0):

Would this query work?

```
SELECT a.date,
a.gran1,
a.gran2,
a.gran3,
b.value1/gran_count AS value1,
b.value2/gran_count AS value2
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
  ON (a.date = b.date
  AND a.gran1 = b.gran1
  AND a.gran2 = b.gran2)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT date, gran1, gran2, count(*) AS gran_count
  FROM table_a
  GROUP BY date, gran1, gran2
) sub ON (a.date = sub.date
  AND a.gran1 = sub.gran1
  AND a.gran2 = sub.gran2);
```

I don't have access to SQL right now so I can't verify the data (or even if I've missed something in the syntax), but I'm attempting to find the COUNT of each combination of date/gran1/gran2 in a subquery, and then use that in a division in the main query.

Both table_b and the subquery (which I've called "sub") are joined to table_a.

There may be a more efficient way of doing this query using two joins instead of three, but nothing comes to mind right now.

Comment: SQL Server requires `GROUP BY` for queries with aggregate functions and additional columns.

Comment: It's weird, both of these queries are giving me the same answer. But the final dataset is always less than the original being joined onto. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Will this till work if there are rows found in TableA not found in TableB?

Comment: sorry I figured out what it was, thanks for your help!